# Cyclic modules over a polynomial ring

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I proved the following proposition.
Is this correct and well-known?

Proposition:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$.
Let $f: V \to V$ a $K$-linear map.
Let $K[X]$ be the polynomial ring.
$V$ can be regarded as a $K[X]$-module via $f$.
If the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is the minimal polynomial, then $V$ is a cyclic $K[X]$-module,
i.e. generated by a single element of $V$ over $K[X]$.

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known result.

Comment: Is there any reference?

Comment: This should be covered in virtually any graduate-level algebra book.  Check the section on modules, or the material leading up to the proof of Jordan canonical form.

Comment: It will also appear in the material leading up to the Rational Canonical Form; e.g., in Friedberg, Insel, and Spence

Comment: @JimBelk "*This should be covered in virtually any graduate-level algebra book.*"
I have Bourbaki and Lang on algebra. I'm afraid I cannot find it covered by them.
Would you please tell me the names of some books that do so?

Comment: It is covered in chapter 3 of Jacobson's Basic Algebra I.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modules_over_a_pid#Invariant_factor_decomposition) $R$, which says that every such module can be written a direct sum of cyclic modules $\bigoplus_{i=1}^lR/(d_i)$ where the generators $d_i$ (invariant factors) divide one another in order: $d_1\mid d_2\mid \cdots \mid d_l$. Take the module to be $V$ as in the question, then the final generator $d_l\in K[X]$ annihilates all the cyclic factors, so (assuming the $d_i$ are taken to be monic) it is the minimal polynomial of $f$, while the characteristic polynomial is the product of all polynomials $d_i$. Clearly the two are equal if and only if $l=1$ (the invariant factors $d_i$ are never $1$) which is the case if and only if $V$ is a cyclic module.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83052/18880) to a related question.