# Are the exercises necessary to understand the subject of a mathematical textbook?

Tags: soft-question, learning

When I am reading a mathematical textbook, I tend to skip most of the exercises.
Generally I don't like exercises, particularly artificial ones.
Instead, I concentrate on understanding proofs of theorems, propositions, lemmas, etc..

Sometimes I try to prove a theorem before reading the proof.
Sometimes I try to find a different proof.
Sometimes I try to find an example or a counter-example.
Sometimes I try to generalize a theorem.
Sometimes I come up with a question and I try to answer it.

I think those are good "exercises" for me.

**EDIT**
What I think is a very good "excercise" is as follows:

(1) Try to prove a theorem before reading the proof.

(2) If you have no idea to prove it, take a look **a bit** at the proof.

(3) Continue to try to prove it.

(4) When you are stuck, take a look **a bit** at the proof.

(5) Repeat (3) and (4) until you come up with a proof.

**EDIT**
Another method I recommend rather than doing "homework type" exercises:
Try to write a "textbook" on the subject.
You don't have to write a real one.
I tried to do this on Galois theory.
Actually I posted "lecture notes" on Galois theory on an internet mathematics forum.
I believe my knowledge and skill on the subject greatly increased.

For example, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131757/a-proof-of-the-normal-basis-theorem-of-a-cyclic-extension-field) while I was writing "lecture notes" on Galois theory.
I could also prove that any profinite group is a Galois group.
This fact was mentioned in Neukirch's algebraic number theory.
I found later that Bourbaki had this problem as an exercise.
I don't understand its hint, though.
Later I found someone wrote a paper on this problem.
I made other small "discoveries" during the course.
I was planning to write a "lecture note" on Grothendieck's Galois theory.
This is an attractive plan, but has not yet been started.

**EDIT**
If you want to have exercises, why not produce them yourself?
When you are learning a subject, you naturally come up with questions.
Some of these can be good exercises. At least you have the motivation not given by others. It is not homework.
For example, I came up with the following question when I was learning algebraic geometry.
I found that this was a good problem.

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $A$ be a finitely generated commutative algebra over $k$.
Let $\mathbb{P}^n = Proj(k[X_0, ... X_n])$.
Determine $Hom_k(Spec(A), \mathbb{P}^n)$.

As I wrote, trying to find examples or counter-examples can be good exercises, too.
For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133790/an-example-of-noncommutative-division-algebra-over-q-other-than-quaternion-alg) is a good exercise in the theory of division algebras.

**EDIT**
Let me show you another example of self-exercises.
I encountered the following problem when I was writing a "lecture note" on Galois theory.

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $K_{sep}$ be a separable algebraic closure of $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $K_{sep}/K$.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over $K$.
If $A$ is isomorphic to a product of fields each of which is separable over $K$, $A$ is called a finite etale algebra.
Let $FinEt(K)$ be the category of finite etale algebra over $K$.

Let $X$ be a finite set.
Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ continuously.
$X$ is called a finite $G$-set.
Let $FinSets(G)$ be the category of finite $G$-sets.

*Then $FinEt(K)$ is anti-equivalent to $FinSets(G)$.*

This is a zero-dimensional version of the main theorem of Grothendieck's Galois theory.
You can find the proof elsewhere, but I recommend you to prove it yourself.
It's not difficult and it's a good exercise of Galois theory.
*Hint*: Reduce it to the the case that $A$ is a finite separable extension of $K$ and X is a finite transitive $G$-set.

**EDIT**
If you think this is too broad a question, you are free to add suitable conditions.
This is a soft question.

Comment: doesn't seem like a very useful question

Comment: The fact that this can vary with the book (including many books, e.g. Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*, that have no exercises) makes it seem too broad.

Comment: A few professors have told me on several occasions that it is often not important to understand the proof of a result, but just that it is true. That being said, I agree that this is a broad question, and depends on personal preference. But, I think most people do a combination of what you seem to be doing, but also solve some exercises. One book that comes to mind for which solving exercises seems to be essential to grasp the subject better is Atiyah-Macdonalds's Commutative Algebra. I don't think I would have learnt a lot just by reading the text and skipping exercises.

Comment: @anthonyquas See my **EDIT**.

Comment: @Rankeya I skipped most of the exercises of Atiyah-MacDonald.
Instead, I read Bourbaki, Matsumura, Zariski-Samuel.

Comment: It would take me a long while to go through the books you mentioned following your approach. I ideally like to try and prove results without seeing the proof, but I make very little progress this way. Do you progress moderately quickly through books using your approach?

Comment: @Rankeya You seem to forget that those books have much more coverage than Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: Deciding on just understanding the theory (and constructing the proofs of theorems) but not actually using the theory to attack any problems reminds me of the following apocryphal tale. A (non-athletically-inclined) faculty member read tennis great Bjorn Borg's comment that tennis was a very simple game; all that needed to be done was to hit the ball over the net one more time than the other guy. He felt he understood the theory perfectly and so promptly entered the tennis tournament at the faculty club. He could not understand why he lost in the first round without winning even one point!

Comment: @Dilip You will use the theory sooner or later, otherwise the theory is not for you.
For example, when you learn commutative algebra, you have to use group theory, field theory, Galois theory, etc.. When you learn algebraic geometry, you have to use commutative algebra, homological algebra, algebraic topology, complex analysis, differential geometry, etc..

Comment: @Rankeya You wrote "Do you progress moderately quickly through books using your approach?" No, but I think it's one of the most effective ways to learn a subject.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, please make your comment an answer. I want to upvote it.

Comment: Also, in my personal experience (not that I have a lot), the difference between reading a textbook and reading a textbook and doing the exercises is the difference between skimming a book and reading a book. It is like having severe astigmatism versus seeing perfectly clearly. It can also be so bad that you don't even realize it. (I've read a chapter and then tried the exercises, only to find that I completely did not understand the chapter.)

Comment: @Dilip You seem to misunderstand my methods. My methods demand *creative* efforts.

Comment: @Limitless You seem to misunderstand my methods, too. Please read all the **EDITs**.

Comment: @MakotoKato, sorry, but you misunderstand. I am not remarking on your methods what-so-ever. In fact, I was remarking entirely on Dilip's opinion. Your methods actually sound good. But I am agreeing with Dilip in the sense that if you _only_ read a textbook, things will be exactly as he has stated. Are we understanding one another?

Answer (score 57):

If your goal is to become a research mathematician, then doing exercises is important.  Of course, there will be the rare person who can skip exercises with no detriment to their development, but (and I speak from the experience of roughly twenty years of involvement in training for research mathematics) such people are genuinely rare.

The other kinds of exercises that you describe are also good, and you should do them too!

The point of doing set exercises is to practice using particular techniques, so that you can recognize how and when to use them when you are confronted with technical obstacles in your research.

In my own field, two books whose exercises I routinely recommend to my students are Hartshorne's *Algebraic geometry* text and Silverman's *Elliptic curves* text.  The exercises at the end of Cassels and Frolich are also good.

Atiyah and MacDonald also is known for its exercises.

One possible approach (not recommended for everyone, though) is to postpone doing exercises if you find them too difficult (or too time-consuming, but this is usually equivalent to too difficult), but to return to them 
later when you feel that you understand the subject better.  However, if upon return, you still can't fairly easily solve standard exercises on a topic you think you know well, you probably don't know the topic as well as you think you do.

---

If your goal is *not* to become a research mathematician, then *understanding* probably has a different meaning and purpose, and your question will then possibly have a different answer, which I am not the right person to give.

Comment: Dear Matt I think many exercises of the Hartshorne's book could be in the main text. Actually many of them are in EGA with full proofs.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Dear Makoto, Yes, that's right.  But having them as exercises to be solved rather than results to be studied gives them a different role in one's training.  (I always approach these sorts of questions from a "training" view-point, whether I'm thinking of my own training or that of my students.)  Best wishes,

Comment: What are some of the things that don't require a full mathematical understanding?

Answer (score 31):

Depends on the textbook, I suppose. Some textbooks introduce a lot of material in the exercises that isn't developed in the main text.

Answer (score 15):

I think that the most important point in mathematics is to think about the subject for long periods of time. If you think about mathematics, then you will often develop intuition which is very important. Of course, if you think about something for long periods of time, then your memory of the material is better as well.

Ultimately, the point is that people generally learn more by doing (compare active learning to passive learning). Of course, there are exceptions to every rule and you are the person who best understands your own strengths and weaknesses. The important point is to identify your weaknesses and work hard on them through a combination of active thinking and problem solving.

Answer (score 9):

Of course this is entirely subjective and depends on your intelligence and memory. I'd suspect most all people on this site are high in both areas, at least in logic/mathematics.

Understanding theorems and working through them like you explained is a very good way to understand material, especially if you can keep it in mind when needed. Exercises are usually repetitious, but also can give you some context that you can/should apply the theorems in.

So, no going through exercises isn't a requirement, but going through some is a good idea to both confirm you understand the material and to help commit that material to memory. That said I wouldn't suggest doing the first few exercises (in most textbooks they're the easiest) rather pick a few in the middle or some that the answer or how to solve them isn't obvious to you. Usually the ones toward the end of a section are either tough, long-winded or both. Doing some of those might be worth it, but some might just be long and strewn out and ultimately not worth the time.

This is just my experience with Math Textbooks, but I've only gotten to the undergraduate level, so how true this is at higher levels I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

absolutely you can't truly say you understand something until you work through it

Answer (score -8):

I'm with the OP on this, I skip exercises too.

Here's the logic: A true understanding of maths is about being creative in its applications and not just the material initself.

Exercises, by definition, stifle creativity by presenting a sandbox in which to think.

It's a bit like Rocky 3, do you learn your craft by working out in a gym or by lifting logs down in the forest?

...and another thing, I reckon following examples in books leads to degenerate mathematics. They perpetuate particular styles of thinking about problems.

Comment: But without exercises, how can you tell that you really understood the definitions and are able to use the definitions and the theorems given in the book?

Comment: Indeed! Both understanding and the value of the mathematics learnt should flow from three things: 1) Internal consistency i.e does it make sense 2) Independence from the body of mathematics already understood 3) Consistency with future mathematics acquired. This approach provides both a valid measure of understanding with the fewest constraints on creativity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think that one can create one's own exercises by asking as many questions as possible. In this way, one practices not only asking questions (which is crucial in research mathematics) but also answering one's own questions. I think doing challenging exercises, if they exist in the textbook, is worthwhile. However, I agree with "@bennyrimmer" in the sense that understanding mathematics on the line by line scale (which people learn by doing exercises) is far less important than understanding mathematics on the larger scale of research (although both are important).

Comment: @Amitesh: Before one do research, one should learn how to do mathematics. Your comment is the root of all crankery, and the lot of people suggesting that they, pure amateurs without any real knowledge or experience can find holes in Godel's theorem; or inconsistencies in set theory. Solving exercises helps you be certain that you understood the theorems and definitions thoroughly. Trust me, I know. I skipped the exercises many times, only to find out many days later that I lacked an essential understanding that would have come from solving the exercises. Doing original research comes *later*.

Comment: @Asaf I never suggested in my comment that one should not do any exercises. However, I do believe that doing too many exercises could be detrimental in the long term for someone aspiring to become a research mathematician (but again this depends on the exercises as I mentioned in my comment above: doing challenging exercises is certainly worthwhile at times). I agree that solving exercises is important but I believe that if one does too many, then one runs the risk of become accustomed to certain trains of thought which narrows one's creativity when thinking about research problems ...

Comment: @Asaf ... Of course, it is important to understand the definitions and theorems in the textbook but if too much effort is spent on this, then the "big picture" can be forgotten. In short, my feeling is that doing exercises helps one to understand the technical details of a subject very well; but research is often about the "big picture" rather than the technical details (this is my impression); if one cannot get ideas, then no amount of technical training will help one to solve research problems ...

Comment: @Asaf ... I say all of this because different people do mathematics in different ways and I believe that one should maintain an open mind as to how mathematics should be done. Of course, I am not an experienced mathematician by any measure of the term but I say this with a fair amount of experience reading textbooks in various branches of mathematics and doing some (not all) of the exercises in these textbooks (and with some experience teaching such mathematics). You are far more qualified than me and I certainly do not mean to contradict you; I am just offering an alternative point of view.

Comment: @Amitesh: What I wrote is coming from an extremely big-picture oriented mind. I hate the details and for me the big picture is the important thing. However mathematics is about proving, not conjecturing. It is rarely the case that my initial guess is successful, and when it is then it always the case that there is some trick holding me back. I still think that one should first solve *some* exercises I never wrote that one should solve all of them. However if one skips them entirely, they will fail at some point. I learned this the hard way.

Comment: @Asaf I certainly agree that not doing any exercises is probably a bad idea in general. I guess what I was saying was that, at the other end of the scale, doing every exercise is probably a bad idea. I never suggested that not doing any exercises is a good idea but I do think that a combination of "@bennyrimmer"'s point of view and the general consensus on exercises in mathematics textbooks could be worthwhile to adopt; that is why I believe that doing too many *challenging* exercises might not be the best idea (instead of doing challenging exercises, I believe one should focus on research).