# Dimension of the vector space containing matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ S=\{A=[a_{ij}] : AB=BA \, \forall B \in M_{n×n} \},$ then $\text{dim}(S)$ equals to?

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. To help others understand how to help you, please give a little more context. Is this a homework question? What are yours thoughts about approaching it?

Comment: Take n=2 and then try to find a pattern.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896979

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP must work before asking such question.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand you can see that $\forall \lambda$ a scalar $\lambda I_n\in S$. We’ll demonstrate that $S=span(I_n)$ and so $dim(S)=1$.

Call $E_{ij}\in M_{n\times n}$ tha matrix such that all of his entries are equal $0$ but the entry $i,j$ equals $1$.
Suppose $A\in S$ then you can see that $AE_{ij}$ is the matrix with all the entries $0$ but the $j$-esim column is equal to the $i$-esim column of $A$ and $E_{ij}A$ is the matrix everywhere $0$ but the $i$-esim row equal to $j$-esim row of $A$. Since $AE_{ij}=E_{ij}A$ $\forall 1\le i,j\le n$ you obtain $A$ must be diagonal.

Can you find another type of matrix with which to verify that all the diagonal entries must be equal?

Comment: For $n=2$, on taking $ A= \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$ and $ B= \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix} ;$  I got $b=c=d=0,$ and $a$ arbitrary. So only $1$ free variable, i.e. $dim(S)=1$

Comment: No: $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
c & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ so you have $c=b=0$ and $a$ and $d$ free parameters

Comment: Yes you are right .. I did mistake in multiplication. Thank you.