# How to prove that the rank of a nonderogatory matrix is at least its order $-1$

Tags: matrix-rank

If $A \in M_{n}$ is nonderogatory, why is rank $A \geq n-1 ?$

Comment: @coffeemath According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_matrices), a matrix with minimal polynomial equal to the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. Just saw that... deleted my c omment.

Comment: If nullity is at least 2, that means in the JNF there are at least two blocks with eigenvalue 0, hence min poly and char poly are not the same.

Comment: For more on non-derogatory matrices, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787796/81360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is non-derogatory, then all eigenvalues of $A$ must have geometric multiplicity $1$.

Comment: I know that. Could you give a detailed proof?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Jordan canonical form of $A$, we have
$A = SJ_AS^{-1}$.

Assume that $J_A=J_{n_{1}}\left(\lambda_{1}\right) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{n_{k}}\left(\lambda_{k}\right)$.

Since the geometric multiplicity of a given eigenvalue of a Jordan matrix is equal to the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to that eigenvalue, a matrix is nonderogatory if and only if each of its distinct eigenvalues corresponds to exactly one block in its Jordan canonical form. Thus, $\lambda_1, \cdots , \lambda_k$ are mutually distinct.

Case 1: $A$ has $0$ eigenvalue. Then by the rank-nullity theorem, we have
$n - rank(A-0I) = 1$, we have $rank A = n-1\ge n-1$

Case 2: $A$ doesn't have $0$ eigenvalue, i.e., $\lambda_i \ne 0, \forall i = 1,\dots, k$. Thus, the rank of A is the number of nonzero rows of $J_A$, i.e., n

To summary, the rank of a nonderogatory matrix is at least its order $-1$.