# What conditions on $X$ and $W$ ensures the vectors $v_i = [\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k ]W$ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, power-series

Let $W$ be a $n$ dimensional real vector. Let $\lambda_i$ be a list of $m$ distinct complex numbers. Let $X$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix whose spectral radius $\rho(X)$ satisfies $\rho(X) \lambda_i < 1$ for all $i$.

What conditions can I impose on $X$ and $W$ to ensure that the vectors

\begin{align*}
v_i = \bigg[\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k \bigg]W
\end{align*}

are linearly independent?

Comment: Some necessary conditions are that $X$ must be [non-derogatory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787796/81360) and $W$ must be a [cyclic vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace). From there, I'm not sure what conditions would need to be imposed on the $\lambda_i$

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that given your conditions, we cannot guarantee that the infinite sum of matrices/vectors converges. We would need a uniform bound, i.e. something let $\rho(X) \lambda_i \leq \alpha$ for some $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: I think you're right about the condition on $\rho(X) \lambda_i$, so I've changed it in the question.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong: I misunderstood what the $\lambda_i$ were. There are finitely many, so saying that $\lambda_i < 1$ for all $i$ is equivalent.

Comment: ahh I understand, you were concerned that $\lambda_i$ could form a sequence that converges to 1?
I'll return the condition to it's original form. Thanks!

Comment: Right, that's the idea. Or that $\rho(X) \lambda_i$ might converge to $1$ as $i \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

As I state in my comment on the question, we require minimally that $X$ is [non-derogatory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787796/81360) and that $W$ is an [$X$-cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_subspace) vector.

With that all stated, we note that if the sum converges, it must satisfy
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k = (I  - \lambda_i X)^{-1}.
$$
Now, there exist coefficients $a^i_k$ such that
$$
(I  - \lambda_i X)^{-1} = a^i_0 I + a^i_1 X + \cdots + a^i_{n-1}X^{n-1}.
$$
Let $v_i = (a_0^i,a_1^i,\dots,a_{n-1}^i) \in \Bbb C^n$. Because the powers $I,X,\dots,X^{n-1}$ are linearly independent, we find that the matrix summation $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k$ are linearly independent if and only if the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent.

With that said: given that the matrices $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k$ are linearly independent, it is not clear how one should choose $W$ to ensure that the vectors $\left[\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k\right]W$ are linearly independent.

---

*Incorrect work:*

Now, suppose that $X$ has characteristic polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, with $a_n = 1$. We note that
$$
a_0 I + a_1 \left[\frac{I - (I - \lambda_i X)}{\lambda_i}\right] + \cdots + a_{n-1}\left[\frac{I - (I - \lambda_i X)}{\lambda_i}\right]^{n-1} + \left[\frac{I - (I - \lambda_i X)}{\lambda_i}\right]^n = 0.
$$
Now, let $q_i(x) = \lambda_i^n p(\frac{1 - x}{\lambda_i}) = \sum_{k=0}^n a^i_k x^k$, with $a^i_n = 1$. We have
$$
a_0^i I + a_1^i (I - \lambda_i X) + \cdots + a_{n-1}^i(I - \lambda_i X)^{n-1} + (I - \lambda_i X)^n = 0 \implies\\
(I - \lambda_i X) \cdot \frac{a_1^i I + \cdots + a_{n-1}^i(I - \lambda_i X)^{n-2} + (I - \lambda_i X)^{n-1}}{-a_0^i}  = I \implies\\
(I - \lambda_i X)^{-1} = \frac{a_1^i I + \cdots + a_{n-1}^i(I - \lambda_i X)^{n-2} + (I - \lambda_i X)^{n-1}}{-a_0^i}.
$$
Now, let $v_i = (a_1^i,\dots,a_{n-1}^i,1) \in \Bbb C^n$. Because the powers $I,X,\dots,X^{n-1}$ are linearly independent, we find that the matrix summation $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} ( X \lambda_i )^k$ are linearly indepednent if and only if the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Hi Ben,

When you write 'incorrect work:' do you mean the work above or below the line is incorrect?

Comment: I think you are onto something here! I will think about this for a while and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @AllenHart I meant the work below; sorry for the confusion. And great!