# Does there exists a matrix A ∈ Mn(F) such that $I, A, A2 , ..., An$ are linearly independent in the vector space Mn(F).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does there exists a matrix A ∈ Mn(F) such that $I, A, A^2 , ..., A^n$ are linearly independent in the vector space Mn(F)?

I'm not sure if this is even true or not. How would i go about solving this?

Comment: Does $A2$ mean $A^2$? Does $An$ mean $A^n$?

Comment: Yes my bad. Edited now

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787796/81360)