# $A$ not decomposable $\Rightarrow$ $m_A=p_A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a field, $A\in Mat_{n,n}(f)$ s.t. $A$ is not decomposable. I want to show (directly!) that the characteristic polynomial $p_A$ of $A$ is equal to the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$.

$A$ is decomposable $\Leftrightarrow\exists V,W: f^n=V \oplus W$ with $V$ and $W$ are $A$-invariant and nonzero.

$V$ subspace of $f^n$ is $A$-invariant $\Leftrightarrow A(V)\subset V$

Comment: What do you mean by directly ?

Comment: Perhaps look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81467/when-are-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials-the-same for help.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Well I can't tell you rigorously what I mean, but the proof shouldn't use something as strong as the jordan normal form. I would guess that this is straightforward to proof, but I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: If the field is complete then its easy, but if its general it seems about as hard as the rational form theorem.