# Which polynomial kernels are cyclic, and how to find a cyclic generator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let $T$ be a $\Bbbk$-linear operator on a vector space $V$. Given $f\in \Bbbk[x]$ consider the operator $f(T)$ on $V$. Write $K(f)=\operatorname{Ker}f(T)$ and call such $T$-invariant subspaces *polynomial kernels*. Let $T_{K(f)}$ be the induced operator on the $T$-invariant subspace $K(f)\leq V$.

**Questions.**

1. Precisely for which $f\in \Bbbk[x]$ is $T_{K(f)}$ a cyclic operator?
2. What's an example of a $T$-cyclic subspace of $V$ which is not a polynomial kernel?
3. What's the algorithm for finding a cyclic generator in the first case?

(Suppose $T$ has a minimal polynomial and that $f\in \Bbbk[x]$ is a monic divisor of it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question is very simple: for $T$ a scalar operator, the only polynomial kernels are the whole space and the zero subspace, so every nontrivial subspace is not a polynomial kernel. The same remains true for any *cyclic* subspace when $T$ is for instance nilpotent with a kernel of dimension${}>1$ (since in the $T$ nilpotent case, every nonzero polynomial kernel contains $\ker(T)$).

Now for the first question.
First of all one can reduce the question to individual irreducible factors of $f$, since $K$ is *canonically* a direct sum of kernels of appropriate powers of such irreducible factors (indeed, the projections to the summands can be written as polynomials in $f$). This means that $K$ is cyclic is and only if all the summands in this decomposition are.

Now assuming $f=p^m$ for some irreducible $p\in k[X]$, on has that $K$ is cyclic if and only if $\ker(p[T])$ is cyclic. One can see that this is so because $\ker(p[T|_W])$ is cyclic for any cyclic submodule $W$ of $K$ (so the stated condition is necessary), and $K$ can always (non canonically) be written as a direct sum of such submodules (whence the condition is sufficient, since a submodule $M$ annihilated by $p$ is cyclic if and only if $\dim(M)\in\{0,\deg(p)\}$).

For your third question, you need to choose a vector$~v$ such that no strict divisor$~d$ of $f$ has $d[T](v)=0$, and this can be done separately for each irreducible factor of$~f$.

You can find more information on this question by looking at the several [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81467) on this site around the question when the minimal polynomial of an operator is equal to its characteristic polynomial.